# Simplest way to exit a thread?

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub that gets a tts voice from the google translate then save it to my localfolder afterwards play it. The problem is the google only accepts 100 characters so i programmed  something to cover that up. and i am using a separate thread to do this.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports NAudio
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports WMPLib
Imports NAudio.Wave
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Sub GoogleTTS(ByVal response As String)
    Try
        Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf downloadFile)
        Player.controls.stop()
        sub_res = response
        If response.Length <= 100 Then
            thread_response = response
            convert_filename = Regex.Replace(response, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", String.Empty)
        Else
            thread_responses = response.Split(CChar(","), CChar("."), CChar("!"), CChar(";"), CChar("?"))
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            ReDim convert_filenames(thread_responses.Count())
            For Each responses As String In thread_responses
                convert_filenames(i) = Regex.Replace(responses, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", String.Empty)
                i += 1
            Next
        End If
        thread.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

   Private Sub downloadFile()
    If sub_res.Length <= 100 Then
        Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("SpeechBank", convert_filename & ".wav")
        If files.Length > 0 Then
            PlayFile("SpeechBank\" & convert_filename & ".wav")
        Else
            Dim HttpReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" & thread_response), HttpWebRequest)
            Using HttpResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(HttpReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                Using Reader As New BinaryReader(HttpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    Dim RdByte As Byte() = Reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10)
                    Using FStream As New FileStream("SpeechBank/" & convert_filename & ".wav", FileMode.Create)
                        FStream.Write(RdByte, 0, RdByte.Length)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            PlayFile("SpeechBank\" & convert_filename & ".wav")
        End If
    ElseIf sub_res.Length > 100 Then   
        ReDim lastFiles(thread_responses.Length - 1)
        For x As Integer = 0 To thread_responses.Length - 1
            Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("SpeechBank", convert_filenames(x) & ".wav")
            If files.Length > 0 Then
                PlayFile("SpeechBank\" & convert_filenames(x) & ".mp3")
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(GetWavFileDuration("SpeechBank\" & convert_filenames(x) & ".mp3"))
            Else
                Dim HttpReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" & thread_responses(x)), HttpWebRequest)
                Using HttpResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(HttpReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                    Using Reader As New BinaryReader(HttpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        Dim RdByte As Byte() = Reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10)
                        Using FStream As New FileStream("SpeechBank\" & convert_filenames(x) & ".wav", FileMode.Create)
                            FStream.Write(RdByte, 0, RdByte.Length)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
                PlayFile("SpeechBank\" & convert_filenames(x) & ".mp3")
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(GetWavFileDuration("SpeechBank\" & convert_filenames(x) & ".mp3"))
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is when i use my GoogleTTS sub and the string I inputed is more than 100 and I followed it up with calling it again with different string in it. the thread seems to overlap and the voice being played at the same time. how can i prevent that?

here is the other pieces of codes for other subs that is included in the googletts sub.

```
Public Sub PlayFile(ByVal url As String)
    Try
        Player = New WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer
        Player.URL = url
        Player.controls.play()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

 Public Function GetWavFileDuration(ByVal fileName As String) As TimeSpan
    Dim wf As New Mp3FileReader(fileName)
    Return wf.TotalTime
End Function


  Public Sub stopFile(ByVal url As String)
    Try
        Player.URL = url
        Player.controls.stop()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thread.Abort - But catch the error in its own try/catch

Comment: i am aware of that thread.abort but i don't now where or when shall i call it.. i tried putting it in the beginning and it seems it disposed my whole thread.

Comment: Your download function should'nt play the file. You can download multiple things at the same time (multiple thread) but you should only be playing one at a time (in one thread).

Comment: oh. that makes sense. but wouldn't it be the same? since if i am going to call it. it will be the same just like before. it will overlap once i call it again before the first thread finishes.